# Curve fitting 3 points

Tags: geometry

I have three points $A$, $B$, and $C$ one of which is on the origin with value of $X$ and $Y$ being $(0,0)$ as shown in the figure. I want to fit a curve to the three points and extrapolate it to point $D$, a fixed distance $ΔY$ from the point $C$. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are known. I know the $Y$ value of $D$ and need to compute the $X$.
Curve Fitting:

[image: Curve Fitting]

So far, I have considered using the quadratic equation form: $y=ax^2+bx+c$.
I would like to get a system of simplified equations given the constraints:

- The first point $A$ will always lie at the origin $(0,0)$;
- The distance $ΔY_{AB}$,  $ΔY_{BC}$ and $ΔY_{CD}$ are fixed constants;
- The points $A$, $B$, and $C$ in special cases, could be co-linear.

If anyone has a better solution for a more 'natural' curve fit, I am open to suggestions. For given values of $X$ for $A$, $B$, and $C$ I need to calculate $Dx$.

Comment: Thank you Travis. In order to extend this question further... if there were a fifth point... could it be that there could be another quadratic curve that fits? Or would a single curve be a fit to 4 points which defines one and only one fifth point on the curve?

Comment: I have the impression you're looking for splines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

you have a model $$f(x) = a x^2 + b x  + c$$ and three points

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| $x_A$ | $y_A$ |
| $x_B$ | $y_B$ |
| $x_C$ | $y_C$ |

you can use those points to create a system of equations

$$\begin{aligned}
 a x_A^2 + b x_A + c & = y_A  \\
 a x_B^2 + b x_B + c & = y_B  \\
 a x_C^2 + b x_C + c & = y_C  \\
\end{aligned}$$

which is solved for $(a,b,c)$ using the following matrix notation

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x_A^2 & x_A & 1 \\
x_B^2 & x_B & 1 \\
x_C^2 & x_C & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} y_A \\ y_B \\ y_C \end{bmatrix}$$

Specifically here with $(x_A,y_A)=(0,0)$ the result is

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{x_B y_C - x_C y_B}{x_B x_C (x_C-x_B)} \\
  \frac{x_B^2 y_C-x_C^2 y_B}{x_B x_C (x_B-x_C)} \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is used in $y_D = f(x_D)$ to estimate the value at point **D**, *if a parabolic model is appropriate.*

> Be wary of naked interpolations where the mathematical model does not have a physical interpretation to it. Those models may fit the existing data very well but fail very quickly when evaluated away from the training region. This is the main struggle with AI models currently which produce results under different assumptions are real life models.

But the same methodology can be applied to any model $f(x)$, as long as the unknown parameters a linear with respect to the coordinates. It does not mater if you are using $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, $\ln(x)$, $\exp(x)$, $\sin(x)$ etc.

Apply the model $f(x)$ to you given points to create an $n$ by $m$ system of equations with $n$ points and $m$ unknown parameters. If $m=n$ then just solve the system

$$ {\rm A}(x) \boldsymbol{c} = \boldsymbol{y}$$

for the coefficients $\boldsymbol{c}$.

and if you have more points than parameters, $m<n$, then use a least-squares solution

$$ \left( {\rm A}^\intercal {\rm A} \right) \boldsymbol{c} = \left( {\rm A}^\intercal \boldsymbol{y} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you John! I am a new user and cannot vote you up. I tried doing various ways ways but this one works.